# Make tbody scrollable with use position:relative in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I want to create table with fixed header. And scroll tbody left and down. If I do thead and tbody as blocks (set style display:block and position:relative) it works for me in all browsers except IE. For IE I need to set position:fixed. But if I use position:fixed after dynamically adding new row the scroll position is reset.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/9nezW/33/

How can I make tbody scrollable with use position:relative in IE?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try setting overflow: auto in the tbody's css.

Comment: Thanks. But it's not helped me

Answer (score 0):

An example I found here: http://monolinea.com/clients/csstests/tablescroll.html has a table that works in IE, still trying to figure out the differences between mine and theirs. May help you to take a look at it's source.

Comment: In example wich you posted for IE "tableContainer" is scrollable and for other browsers - "tbody". In my case I want to make "tbody" scrollable for all browsers.

Comment: Yeah, after fighting with it for quite awhile I got it working.. but only in IE9 Compatibility mode with IE conditional statements. Still not good enough for what I'm trying to do.

I'm now looking into using this instead. http://fixedheadertable.com

Comment: This is good solution for table which will be scrolled down only. On my site I have very big table. And I want to make it scrollable to left and down. In this example I set fixedColumn "on" and tried to scroll left and right. The header was slided slow in FF 4.0